# Need the commands to be passed in .gitlab-ci.yml file to run karate ui coding in gitlab CI/CD pipeline

Tags: karate

I want to run CI/CD pipeline in gitlab for my karate ui automated scripts. Need the steps to be provided in .gitlab-ci.yml file thats working as expected making the automated scripts run successfully in pipeline. Am using maven.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you share some code? What's the problem you're encountering?

Comment: to OP - if you are using a junit entry point, the exact same recipe you use for JUnit will work for karate. also refer: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bkarate%5D+gitlab